# ios xamarin.inappbilling plugin exception cant connect to itunes localization issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase

My app was approved in the apple store with subscription billing. The paid subscription is working for friends of mine, however I am logging into my database any billing exceptions and am seeing the exceptions "cant connect to itunes".

Since it is working for me and my friends(in America), I am assuming it is a localization issue.

In itunes connect I added localizations for every country under the iap and subscription group. Is there anything else needed for localization?

Comment: Have you read [issue1](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/77) and [issue2](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/37)?

Comment: Yes, I am still not sure why mine is not working. It is working for friends of mine, but not for other users who I am assuming are from other countries